# yarn outdated showing showing all bower_components

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bower, yarnpkg

I used bower-away and migrated away from Bower to use Yarn.
However when I run Yarn outdated it will always show my Yarn Bower components as outdated for some reason. 
Why is this happening? 
How can I make it go away?

```
Package                               Current Wanted Latest  Package Type URL                                                     
@bower_components/angular             1.2.32  exotic exotic  dependencies angular/bower-angular#1.2.32                            
@bower_components/angular-animate     1.2.32  exotic exotic  dependencies angular/bower-angular-animate#~1.2                      
@bower_components/angular-bootstrap   0.0.0   exotic exotic  dependencies angular-ui/bootstrap-bower#~0.11.0                      
@bower_components/angular-cookies     1.2.32  exotic exotic  dependencies angular/bower-angular-cookies#~1.2                      
@bower_components/angular-growl-v2    0.7.9   exotic exotic  dependencies JanStevens/angular-growl-2#^0.7.9                       
@bower_components/angular-mocks       1.2.32  exotic exotic  dependencies angular/bower-angular-mocks#~1.2                        
@bower_components/angular-resource    1.2.32  exotic exotic  dependencies angular/bower-angular-resource#~1.2                     
@bower_components/angular-sanitize    1.2.32  exotic exotic  dependencies angular/bower-angular-sanitize#~1.2                     
@bower_components/angular-ui-router   0.0.0   exotic exotic  dependencies angular-ui/angular-ui-router-bower#~0.2.10              
@bower_components/angular-ui-utils    0.0.0   exotic exotic  dependencies angular-ui/ui-utils#~0.1.1                              
@bower_components/bootstrap           3.1.1   exotic exotic  dependencies twbs/bootstrap#~3.1.1                                   
@bower_components/font-awesome        4.1.0   exotic exotic  dependencies FortAwesome/Font-Awesome#~4.1.0                         
@bower_components/jquery              2.1.4   exotic exotic  dependencies jquery/jquery-dist#~2.1.1                               
@bower_components/lodash              2.4.2   exotic exotic  dependencies lodash/lodash#~2.4.1                                    
@bower_components/ngActivityIndicator 0.1.10  exotic exotic  dependencies voronianski/ngActivityIndicator#^0.1.5                  
@bower_components/papaparse           4.1.2   exotic exotic  dependencies mholt/PapaParse#fbf22867bfc6280192c5267cab84eadf50307170
@bower_components/socket.io           1.0.6   exotic exotic  dependencies LearnBoost/socket.io#~1.0.6
```